# Ignore case in glob() on Linux

Tags: python, linux

I'm writing a script which will have to work on directories which are modified by hand by Windows and Linux users alike. The Windows users tend to not care at all about case in assigning filenames.

Is there a way to handle this on the Linux side in Python, i.e. can I get a case-insensitive, glob-like behaviour?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use case-insensitive regexes instead of glob patterns. [`fnmatch.translate`](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.translate) generates a regex from a glob pattern, so

```
re.compile(fnmatch.translate(pattern), re.IGNORECASE)
```

gives you a case-insensitive version of a glob pattern as a compiled RE.

Keep in mind that, if the filesystem is hosted by a Linux box on a Unix-like filesystem, users will be able to create files `foo`, `Foo` and `FOO` in the same directory.

Comment: cool 8) is there also a function to then return the list of matching filenames, or do i manually have to go through cascades of os.listdir()?

Comment: after 2 hours of fiddling around with `os.walk`, i'm at at a loss. could you please advice a bit more? i'm having a hard time figuring out the looping around the `dirs`, matching the `re` and breaking appropriately. probably not my day :(

Comment: @andreash: `os.walk` returns triples `(basepath, dirs, files)` s.t. you can get the relative path to a dir or file by joining it (`os.path.join`) with `basepath`. You can then try to match the result with your pattern.

Comment: i'll accept this answer, as it gives a valid response. however, i decided to use a more tailor-made combination of `os.walk` and `os.listdir`, for speed reasons.

Answer (score 62):

You can replace each alphabetic character c with [cC], via

```
import glob
def insensitive_glob(pattern):
    def either(c):
        return '[%s%s]' % (c.lower(), c.upper()) if c.isalpha() else c
    return glob.glob(''.join(map(either, pattern)))
```

Comment: To be a little more pythonic...or at least make pylint happy
`return glob.glob(''.join(either(char) for char in pattern))`

Comment: shao.lo: Yes, that does have the advantage of being longer.

Comment: This solution has serious drawbacks, so be careful. First, ```glob()``` will fail using this kind of pattern on Windows drive letter. Then, the same apply when using "magic" folders such as "sysnative" folder.

Comment: This seems hacky, but yeah it gets the job done doesn't it. It works fine for me.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving Ha, and slower...(pattern of size 1k shown)

```python
In[10] %timeit ''.join(either(char) for char in pattern)
392 µs ± 5.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In[11] %timeit ''.join(map(either, pattern))
358 µs ± 7.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: @craymichael it looks like you can shave another 10% off the runtime in Python 3.6+ by using `f'[{c.lower()}{c.upper()}]'` instead of the `%` operator to create the string. I also find that pretty legible with appropriate syntax highlighting!

Answer (score 9):

### Non recursively

In order to retrieve the files (and files only) of a directory "path", with "globexpression":

```py
list_path = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, i))]
result = [os.path.join(path, j) for j in list_path if re.match(fnmatch.translate(globexpression), j, re.IGNORECASE)]
```

### Recursively

with walk:

```py
result = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    result += [os.path.join(root, j) for j in files \
        if re.match(fnmatch.translate(globexpression), j, re.IGNORECASE)]
```

Better also compile the regular expression, so instead of

```py
re.match(fnmatch.translate(globexpression)
```

do (before the loop):

```py
reg_expr = re.compile(fnmatch.translate(globexpression), re.IGNORECASE)
```

and then replace in the loop:

```py
result += [os.path.join(root, j) for j in files if re.match(reg_expr, j)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my non-recursive file search for Python with glob like behavior for Python 3.5+

```
# Eg: find_files('~/Downloads', '*.Xls', ignore_case=True)
def find_files(path: str, glob_pat: str, ignore_case: bool = False):
    rule = re.compile(fnmatch.translate(glob_pat), re.IGNORECASE) if ignore_case \
            else re.compile(fnmatch.translate(glob_pat))
    return [n for n in os.listdir(os.path.expanduser(path)) if rule.match(n)]
```

Note: This version handles [home directory expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24680001/286807)

Comment: This works except one cannot use wildcards anywhere in the path, only in the file.

Comment: @MatthewSnyder - Thanks. When I get some time, I'll update it to handle wildcards in path also.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from [python-3.12](/questions/tagged/python-3.12), you can use [`Path.glob(pattern, *, case_sensitive=None)` API with `case_sensitive` argument set to `False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) to get the desired behavior.

> By default, or when the `case_sensitive` keyword-only argument is set to
> `None`, this method matches paths using platform-specific casing rules:
> typically, case-sensitive on *POSIX*, and case-insensitive on *Windows*.
> Set `case_sensitive` to `True` or `False` to override this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your case, you might use `.lower()` on both file pattern and results from folder listing and only then compare the pattern with the filename

Answer (score 1):

Riffing off of @Timothy C. Quinn's answer, this modification allows the use of wildcards anywhere in the path. This is admittedly only case insensitive for the glob_pat argument.

```
import re
import os
import fnmatch
import glob

def find_files(path: str, glob_pat: str, ignore_case: bool = False):
    rule = re.compile(fnmatch.translate(glob_pat), re.IGNORECASE) if ignore_case \
            else re.compile(fnmatch.translate(glob_pat))
    return [n for n in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*')) if rule.match(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with `fnmatch.translate()`:

```py
from glob import glob
from pathlib import Path
import fnmatch, re


mask_str = '"*_*_yyww.TXT" | "*_yyww.TXT" | "*_*_yyww_*.TXT" | "*_yyww_*.TXT"'
masks_list = ["yyyy", "yy", "mmmmm", "mmm", "mm", "#d", "#w", "#m", "ww"]

for mask_item in masks_list:
    mask_str = mask_str.replace(mask_item, "*")

clean_quotes_and_spaces = mask_str.replace(" ", "").replace('"', '')
remove_double_star = clean_quotes_and_spaces.replace("**", "*")
masks = remove_double_star.split("|")

cwd = Path.cwd()

files = list(cwd.glob('*'))
print(files)

files_found = set()

for mask in masks:
    mask = re.compile(fnmatch.translate(mask), re.IGNORECASE)
    print(mask)

    for file in files:        
        if mask.match(str(file)):
            files_found.add(file)         

print(files_found)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted a variant of this where I only went case insensitive if I was specifying a file extension -- eg, I wanted ".jpg" and ".JPG" to be crawled the same. This is my variant:

```py
import re
import glob
import os
from fnmatch import translate as regexGlob
from platform import system as getOS

def linuxGlob(globPattern:str) -> frozenset:
    """
    Glob with a case-insensitive file extension
    """
    base = set(glob.glob(globPattern, recursive= True))
    maybeExt = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(globPattern))[1][1:]
    caseChange = set()
    # Now only try the extended insensitivity if we've got a file extension
    if len(maybeExt) > 0 and getOS() != "Windows":
        rule = re.compile(regexGlob(globPattern), re.IGNORECASE)
        endIndex = globPattern.find("*")
        if endIndex == -1:
            endIndex = len(globPattern)
        crawl = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(globPattern[:endIndex]), "**", "*")
        checkSet = set(glob.glob(crawl, recursive= True)) - base
        caseChange = set([x for x in checkSet if rule.match(x)])
    return frozenset(base.union(caseChange))
```

I didn't actually restrict the insensitivity to *just* the extension because I was lazy, but that confusion space is pretty small (eg, you'd want to capture `FOO.jpg` and `FOO.JPG` but *not* `foo.JPG` or `foo.jpg`; if your path is that pathological you've got other problems)

Answer (score 0):

```
def insensitive_glob(pattern):
    def either(c):
        return '[%s%s]' % (c.lower(), c.upper()) if c.isalpha() else c
    return glob.glob(''.join(map(either, pattern)))
```

also can be:

```
def insensitive_glob(pattern):
    return glob.glob(
        ''.join([
            '[' + c.lower() + c.upper() + ']'
            if c.isalpha() else c
            for c in pattern
        ])
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

a variation of your answer with search recursive of names files :

```
def insensitive_for_glob(string_file):
    return ''.join(['[' + c.lower() + c.upper() + ']' if c.isalpha() else c for c in string_file])
```

in otherplace in code :

```
namefile = self.insensitive_for_glob(namefile)
lst_found_file = glob.glob(f'{file_path}/**/*{namefile}', recursive=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply search for upper and lower cases and then add the results like so:

```
from pathlib import Path folder = Path('some_folder')
file_filter = '.txt' 
files_in_folder = [files for files in (
    list(folder.glob(f'*{file_filter.lower()}'))+
    list(folder.glob(f'*{file_filter.upper()}'))
)]
```

This will find files both with `.txt` as well as `.TXT` endings.