# how to take caer case mismtaches of a usercreated file

Tags: python

I am picking up some info from the file "data_file.txt",its a file created by enduser but if the user creates it with different cases like Data_file.txt or data_FILE.txt or so on...how can I take care in the script to accommodate such case-mistmatch scenarios?

```
def getAU (aufilename):
    file = open(aufilename,'r')
    return file.read()

def main ():
    aufilename="data_file.txt"
    #ROOT_DIR - The reference android build used to make the builds
    AU=getAU(aufilename)
    ROOT_DIR= "/local/mnt/workspace/username/LA_CI/" + AU
    print ROOT_DIR

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151300/ignore-case-in-glob-on-linux , `insensitive_glob()` should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply open a file without regard to the case of the filename unless your filesystem uses case-insensitive file names.  Try something like:

```
import os
def case_insensitive_open(filename, mode='r'):
    dir = os.path.dirname(filename)
    for potential_match in os.listdir(dir):
        if potential_match.lower() == filename.lower():
             return open(os.path.join(dir, potential_match), mode)
    else:
        return open(potential_match, mode)
```

This will raise an `IOError` if it reaches the `else` clause unless you open the file for writing, just like a regular `open()` call would.

Answer (score 4):

Get a list of files in the expected location with `os.listdir()`, then for each file there, flatten the filename to lower case and compare it with `"data_file.txt"`. Note, though, that on systems where file case is significant, you may find both a `Data_file.txt` and a `data_FILE.txt`, and you need to think hard about how to handle that case -- open an arbitrary one of the two, open the most recent one of the two, or report an error?