# Why is os.path.expanduser not returning the home directory?

Tags: python, windows, path, os.path

I am making a python desktop application that saves a log as a .csv file in the user's Documents folder on Windows. The application is written in python 2.7 and kivy 1.8.0, packaged as a Windows program using pyinstaller 2.1, and the installer is made using Inno Setup Compiler. In this post, I will replace the user's real name with USER.

I have the following lines of code:

```
DOCUMENTS = os.path.expanduser('~\\Documents\\')
print DOCUMENTS
with open(DOCUMENTS + 'data_log.csv', 'ab') as f:
    do stuff
```

On my computer and one other I've tested it on, the program works as expected. DOCUMENTS evaluates to 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\'. However, on the three other computers I've tried, DOCUMENTS evaluates to 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\SPB_16.6\Documents\'. The program then crashes when it tries to create data_log.csv, giving the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\Roaming\\SPB_16.6\\Documents\\data_log.csv'
```

First, why might os.path.expanduser misbehave on certain systems, but not on others?

<strike>Second, even if it's in the wrong directory, open() should create the file if it doesn't exist, so why is that causing it to crash?</strike>

I've figured out what's causing this problem. On most systems, HOME is None, so os.path.expanduser uses USERPROFILE instead. However, in rare cases HOME is set to something like C:\SPB\ or C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\SPB_16.6. My solution is to use os.environ to access USERPROFILE directly instead of using os.path.expanduser.

Comment: Is there any major difference between the machines it crashes on and the machines it works on?

Comment: Nothing I can think of. The 2 that it works on both have Windows 7, but it crashes on other Windows 7 machines and the one Windows 8 machine that was available. None of the users could have changed any hidden system settings, environment variables, etc. on any of the machines.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of `expanduser`:

> On Windows, HOME and USERPROFILE will be used if set, otherwise a
>   combination of HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE will be used. An initial ~user
>   is handled by stripping the last directory component from the created
>   user path derived above.

As you can see, the code is extremely simple (dumped with `inspect`):

```
def expanduser(path):
    """Expand ~ and ~user constructs.

    If user or $HOME is unknown, do nothing."""
    if path[:1] != '~':
        return path
    i, n = 1, len(path)
    while i < n and path[i] not in '/\\':
        i = i + 1

    if 'HOME' in os.environ:
        userhome = os.environ['HOME']
    elif 'USERPROFILE' in os.environ:
        userhome = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
    elif not 'HOMEPATH' in os.environ:
        return path
    else:
        try:
            drive = os.environ['HOMEDRIVE']
        except KeyError:
            drive = ''
        userhome = join(drive, os.environ['HOMEPATH'])

    if i != 1: #~user
        userhome = join(dirname(userhome), path[1:i])

    return userhome + path[i:]
```

There's not much that can go wrong with `expanduser` itself. You'll want to check those environment variables inside your program to see if they hold the correct values.

```
    import os
    for var in ('HOME', 'USERPROFILE', 'HOMEPATH', 'HOMEDRIVE'):
        print os.environ.get(var)
```

A likely reason `open` may be failing is that the directory where you're trying to open the file doesn't exist, or you don't have permissions to access it.

Comment: They hold the correct values, but I still get this error.

Comment: @user268639 Can we get more details? What are the specific values for those variables in the "bad" systems?

Comment: @user268639 Also, importantly, how are you executing the script? Directly from the console? Or is it launched by other application?

Comment: If the OP had no write permissions there would be a permission denied error

Comment: It is difficult to gather details because I am simply asking friends and colleagues to run the program rather than having complete access to the computers myself. Anyway, on my "good" system the HOME is None, USERPROFILE is C:\Users\MyName, HOMEPATH is \Users\MyName and HOMEDRIVE is C:. On one of the "bad" systems, they are exactly the same (with MyName changed, of course).

Comment: I packaged the script as a Windows program using PyInstaller. Then, I made an installer program using Inno Setup Compiler. The installer installs the program like a typical Windows program, and it's being launched through a desktop shortcut.  

Yes, open() must be failing because there is no Documents folder in the directory that the "bad" systems are erroneously pointing to.

Comment: @user268639 You should check the values of the variables *inside* your program (see my previous edit)