# making subprocess.Popen switch directory's and do a command with path isn't known python

Tags: python, windows, path, subprocess

working in python and trying to make a subprocess work in a different directory from parent. made a super simplified test version and its not working

```
def test:
   testPath1 = 'C:\\"%HOMEPATH%"\\Desktop'
   testPath2 = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop'
   subprocess.Popen('dir', cwd=testPath1, shell=True)
test()
```

this code works for testPath2 but not for testPath1

error:
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid

however if I physically type 'cd C:"%HOMEPATH%"\Desktop' into a terminal it does work and does go there, so the path 'does' work.  but this code just isn't....

any ideas or recommendations?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679918/why-is-os-path-expanduser-not-returning-the-home-directory

Answer (score 0):

A friend showed me a great solution with using pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path

home = Path.home()

# if you want the Desktop dir you do
desktop = home / 'Desktop'

# then you can check if it exists
if desktop.exists():
    # do stuff
```

this was able to solve my issues and help my code work even in linux or mac, not just windows.

Hope this helps anyone else who had similar issues in the future.