# Python get file regardless of upper or lower

Tags: python, python-2.7, glob, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151300/ignore-case-in-glob-on-linux) on my program to get an mp3 file regardless of case, and I've this code:

```
import glob
import fnmatch, re

def custom_song(name):
    for song in re.compile(fnmatch.translate(glob.glob("../music/*"+name+"*.mp3")), re.IGNORECASE):
        print (song)
custom_song("hello")
```

But when I execute the script i get the following error:

```
 File "music.py", line 4, in custom_song
    for song in re.compile(fnmatch.translate(glob.glob("../music/*"+name+"*.mp3")), re.IGNORECASE):
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object is not iterable
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fnmatch.translate` expects a string as an argument, not a list/iterator of filenames as would be returned by glob, thus something like:

```
pattern = re.compile(fnmatch.translate(name + "*.mp3"), 
    re.IGNORECASE)
```

Also, you must iterate over some filenames and see if they `match` the compiled pattern:

```
directory = '../music/'
for name in os.listdir(directory):
    if pattern.match(name):
        print(os.path.join(directory, name))
```