# Glob fetching pdf files with lower or upper .pdf extension

Tags: python

I have a piece of code which traverses through the directory using os.walk and then in the corresponding directoy gets the file list of all pdf files there.

For getting the list of pdf files in a particular directory after traversal I use glob like below:

```
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(root,invoice_dir_name, "*.pdf"))
```

It fetches all files in a directory which end with .pdf.

But I just found a corner case where if the directory has pdf files but if they end in .PDF it returns empty string as it's looking for lower case .pdf extension.

How can I add regular expression in the glob function so it can fetch either of .pdf or .PDF. I tried

```
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(root,invoice_dir_name, "*.(pdf|PDF)"))
```

but obviously it doesn't work

My code uses glob and os.walk and any other things asked to use would be a redo of code so I was wondering if a soln can be found with glob. Thanks

Comment: I guess you can call glob twice, and put all results into one list and then process it

Comment: that won't work. Glob is run for each sub directory in main directory. For one sub it works as it has .pdf files.. other it doesn't as it has .PDF

Comment: i'd say it's not different from what you already did, let me share a code.

Comment: `glob.glob(os.path.join(root,invoice_dir_name, "*.pdf"))` should work for both....i believe `glob` pattern is case insensitive

Comment: on mac also it does;n't work. Glob is not case insensitive

Comment: This question already answered. Try [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973384/python-get-file-regardless-of-upper-or-lower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973384/python-get-file-regardless-of-upper-or-lower)

Answer (score 1):

How about searching for **.pdf & .PDF** separately and collecting the info into single list? This way, matches found for both patterns would be combined and returned.

```
def get_files(root, dir_name, pattern):
    patterns = [os.path.join(root, dir_name, pattern.upper()), os.path.join(root, dir_name, pattern.lower())]
    return [filename for p in patterns for filename in glob.glob(p)]
```

If not a new function, then simply replace:

```
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(root,invoice_dir_name, "*.pdf"))
```

with:

```py
pattern = "*.pdf"
p_lower = os.path.join(root, dir_name, pattern.upper())
p_upper = os.path.join(root, dir_name, pattern.lower())
file_list = [fname for p in (p_lower, p_upper) for fname in glob.glob(p)]
```

**Output:**

```
[
  '/Users/username/docs/37-sbc-sleep-apnea-2018.PDF',
  '/Users/username/docs/notice.pdf',
  '/Users/username/docs/Health2020.pdf',
  '/Users/username/docs/West.pdf',
  '/Users/username/docs/hello-Health-net-excel-file-2020.pdf', 
  '/Users/username/docs/2018-arbitration-form-english.pdf'
]
```

Comment: not using another function there. Is there a way it can be done w/o using another function. I tried using os.listdir like below instead of glob like below: 

file_list = [os.path.join(root, invoice_dir_name, file_name) for file_name in 
                            os.listdir(os.path.join(root,invoice_dir_name))]

problem is if there is any other file other than  pdf os.listdir also picks up that and then my code further throws an error as it only expects pdf file.So if os.listdir as above can only take pdf files then that can work too

Comment: yeah on using listdir, you'll need to filter the unwanted ones again. lets not take that direction. instead just tell glob to pick both pdf & PDF, shouldn't be an expensive op.

Comment: That doesn't work as when u join p_lower u r just using *.pdf there. It would not give the full name of file. 

I did this and it works. I filter out the files which end in .pdf from os.listdir

file_list = os.listdir(os.path.join(root,invoice_dir_name))
file_list_pdf = [os.path.join(root, invoice_dir_name, file_name) for file_name in 
                             file_list if file_name.lower().endswith(".pdf")]

Comment: glob should use the pattern to match but return **absolute path** of files.

Comment: do u feel any issue might be with the os.listdir I used with filter on .endswith()? I think it should cover all issues

Comment: depends. when most of files inside dir are pdf, your code makes more sense.