# Case Sensitive file path matching in Python

Tags: python-3.x, directory

I have a directory with this path

> Al Furjan/Al Furjan 2D 3D/3D/AZIZI tulip/file.jpg

I have another csv from which i am creating the path and the path becomes like this

> Al Furjan/Al Furjan 2D 3D/3D/AZIZI Tulip/file.jpg

The path i am generating has **T** capital, but the actual directory has **small** **t**. How can i cater this issue with python, that it ignores the case sensitivity while searching through paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conjunction of `fnmatch`, `re` and `os` to do this:

```
import os
import fnmatch
import re

# translate the file name in a pattern
regex = fnmatch.translate('testit/testIT/testIT.txt')

# compile a case insensitive version of your this pattern
rec = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)

def listallfiles(path):
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
        for f in filenames:
            yield(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(dirpath, f)))

found = [i for i in listallfiles('.') if rec.match(i)] 

print(found)
```

Comment: I found similar solution as well as others in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151300/ignore-case-in-glob-on-linux

Comment: I tried that solutions, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Can you share an exmaple of it ?

Comment: I have completely restarted it, the use of glob was misleading.  I have rather used os.walk with an iterator.