# Make pathlib.glob() and pathlib.rglob() case-insensitive for platform-agnostic application

Tags: python, cross-platform, glob, case-sensitive, pathlib

I am using [`pathlib.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) and [`pathlib.rglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) to matching files from a directory and its subdirectories, respectively. Target files both are both lower case `.txt` and upper case `.TXT` files. According file paths were read from the filesystem as follows:

```
import pathlib

directory = pathlib.Path()
files_to_create = ['a.txt', 'b.TXT']
suffixes_to_test = ['*.txt', '*.TXT']

for filename in files_to_create:
    filepath = directory / filename
    filepath.touch()
    
for suffix in suffixes_to_test:
    files = [fp.relative_to(directory) for fp in directory.glob(suffix)]
    print(f'{suffix}: {files}')
```

The majority of the code base was developed on a Windows 10 machine (running Python 3.7.4) and was now moved to macOS Monterey 12.0.1 (running Python 3.10.1).

On Windows both files `a.txt` and `b.TXT` are matching the patterns:

```
*.txt: [WindowsPath('a.txt'), WindowsPath('b.TXT')]
*.TXT: [WindowsPath('a.txt'), WindowsPath('b.TXT')]
```

In contrast, macOS only one file matches each pattern:

```
*.txt: [PosixPath('a.txt')]
*.TXT: [PosixPath('b.TXT')]
```

Therefore, I assume that the macOS file system might be case-sensitive, whereas the Windows one is not. According to [Apple's User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/file-system-formats-dsku19ed921c/mac) the macOS file system used should not be case-sensitive by default but can be configured as such.
Something similar might apply for Linux or Unix file systems as discussed [here](https://superuser.com/q/431342/526971) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/358395/183170).

Despite the reason for this differing behavior, I need to find a platform-agnostic way to get both capital `TXT` and lower case `txt` files.
A rather naive workaround could be something like this:

```
results = set([fp.relative_to(directory) for suffix in suffixes_to_test for fp in directory.glob(suffix)])
```

Which gives the desired output on both macOS and Windows:

```
{PosixPath('b.TXT'), PosixPath('a.txt')}
```

However, is there a more elegant way? I could not find any option like `ignore_case` in [pathlib's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like:

```
suffix = '*.[tT][xX][tT]'
files = [fp.relative_to(directory) for fp in directory.glob(suffix)]
```

It is not so generalizable for a "case-insensitive glob", but it works well for limited and specific use-case like your glob of a specific extension.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the syntax:

```py
import pathlib

directory = pathlib.Path()
files_to_create = ['a.txt', 'b.TXT']

for filename.lower() in files_to_create:
    filepath = directory / filename
    filepath.touch()

files = [fp.relative_to(directory) for fp in directory.glob("*.[tT][xX][tT]")]
```

This would match all case combinations of txt.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not wanting case sensitive then you could set the case to lower or upper.

```
import pathlib

directory = pathlib.Path()
files_to_create = ['a.txt', 'b.TXT']
suffixes_to_test = ['*.txt']

for filename.lower() in files_to_create:
    filepath = directory / filename
    filepath.touch()

for suffix.lower() in suffixes_to_test:
    files = [fp.relative_to(directory) for fp in directory.glob(suffix)]
    print(f'{suffix}: {files}')
```

This will give different output to your example of desired output but also might be what you are asking?

You might also draw inspiration from answers here: [Ignore case in glob() on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151300/ignore-case-in-glob-on-linux)

If you *do* want to be case sensitive then you might adapt those answers and use the `fnmatch.fnmatchcase` method to make the Windows behaviour case sensitive.

Un-tried but probably something like;

```
import pathlib

directory = pathlib.Path()
files_to_create = ['a.txt', 'b.TXT']
suffixes_to_test = ['*.txt', '*.TXT']

for filename in files_to_create:
    filepath = directory / filename
    filepath.touch()
    
for suffix in suffixes_to_test:
    files = [fp.relative_to(directory) for fp in directory.glob('*') if fnmatch.fnmatchcase(f'{fp}', suffix)]
    print(f'{suffix}: {files}')
```

Comment: However, this solution will only match either lower or upper case. If your extensions are e.g. `.Txt` it will not work. So it's not really case-insensitive.

Comment: That's true. But does address the OPs target.  
If the solution should address any permutation of cases then a different approach should probably be taken.