# Match folder names

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, operating-system

My code:

```
path = 'c:/users/student/pythonprojects'
path = os.realname(path) # A function that converts it to the real path names
print(path)
```

Expected output:

```
>>> 'C:/Users/Student/PythonProjects'
```

I don't want it to just capitalize the words. I want it to convert to the real folder names in the computer.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10886685/11107859 The `insensitive_glob` is what you are looking for

Comment: when i run ```insensitive_glob(path)``` it returns ```[]``` am I doing right?

Comment: I saw in the answer comments that it have an issue with Windows drive letters. Could you try to check the result of it with `path = r'C:\mydir\file.txt'`? Note the `r` in the begging of the string and '\' instead of '/'

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such function as os.realname() in Python. However, you can use the os.path.realpath() function to convert a relative path to an absolute path. For example:

```
import os
path = 'c:/users/student/pythonprojects'
path = os.path.realpath(path)
print(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a trivial question, as path are case sensitive you can have multiple matches (FiLe.txt, FILE.txt, file.txt) can all exists in the same directory.

If you don't have such issues you can always compare name in lower case if they match use the correct path.

Use [os.path.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive) and [os.path.splitdrive()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive) to separate component of the path and check recursively each path from the drive letter to the file.